# Convergence in measure implies convergence in $L^p$ under the hypothesis of domination

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Given a sequence $f_n \in L^p$ and $g \in L^p$, with $|f_n| \leq g$, I am trying to show that $f_n \to f$ in measure implies $f_n \to f$ in $L^p$.

Firstly, I know that if $f_n \to f$ in measure, then there is a subsequence $f_{n_i}$ such that $f_{n_i} \to f$ almost everywhere. Then I can use the dominated convergence theorem to show that $\lVert f_{n_i} - f_p\rVert \to 0$.

Now I am trying to show that $\lVert f_n - f\rVert_p \to 0$. My idea is to assume that $\lVert f_n - f\rVert_p \nrightarrow 0$ and then show that this contradicts the fact that $\lVert f_{n_i} - f\rVert_p \to 0$, but I am not sure of the details. Can anyone help me finish the argument?

Comment: In the title, you should add "with an hypothesis of domination". You are almost done: if $||f_n-f||_p$ doesn't converge to $0$, then we can find $\delta>0$ and a subsequence such that $||f_{n_k}-f||\geq \delta$. This subsequence still converges in measure to $f$, so by your previous argument we get a contradiction.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Ok, got it. Thanks!

Comment: You can answer your own question (hence it won't remain unanswered), and you will have your homework done properly.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo : as one commenter makes note of below, we haven't used the boundedness of $f_n$ at all. Is this a problem?

Comment: Also, this question was featured on the UI-Urbana Champaign graduate qualifying exam from August 2015, if anyone cares to know.

Answer (score 18):

If $\lVert f_n - f\rVert_p \nrightarrow 0$, there exist a subsequence $ f_{n_i} $ such that $ \| f_{n_i} - f\|
_p \ge \varepsilon $ for some $ \varepsilon >0 $. But $ f_{n_i} $ still converges in measure to $ f $. So, again There is a subsequence $ f_{n_{i_j}} $ of the $ f_{n_i} $ such that $ \|f_{n_{i_j}} - f\|_p \rightarrow 0$, and this is a contradiction.

Comment: How does the boundedness of $\|fn\|$ work in your argument?

Comment: To claim the fact that $\|f_{n_{i_j}} - f\|_p \rightarrow 0$ you would need to apply Dominated convergence theorem in $L^p$ setting, there you would need boundedness of $f_n$

Comment: you need this information to apply the domited convergence theorem.

Comment: how do you use the dominated convergence?

Comment: I don't see why the sequences must agree. That is, the sub-sequence from $\mu$-a.e. convergence may be a different sub-sequence than the $||f_{n_i}-f||_p>\delta$, right?